# Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

There is the possibility to add a custom image from URI inside a Notification?
For example:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "something", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I would insert an image from URI instead from drawable resources.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When using `Notification.Builder` (apilevel > 11), you can use any `Bitmap` as large icon: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: if my answer solves your problem, please tick my answer as Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
// Large icon for notification with add a custom image from URI 
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
builder.setLargeIcon(bmp);
```

**Above code in Notiifcation Builder.**

```
public void DisplayNotification() {

// Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

//icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);

// This intent is fired when notification is clicked
Intent tapIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, tapIntent, 0);

// Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// Large icon appears on the left of the notification
 Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
builder.setLargeIcon(bmp);

// Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
builder.setContentTitle("Notifications Title");

// Content text, which appears in smaller text below the title
builder.setContentText("Your notification content here.");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Will display the notification in the notification bar
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Happy Coding :)